# Suppress WebBrowser JavaScript message error

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls

I use in an WPF project a XAML-components with a WebBrowser Control. In it, I load a page by the user is prompted to enter login information. After the login procedure, I get a JavaScript error message. I trace the Web page in Internet Explorer, this error message by the settings of Internet Explorer is suppressed. Is it possible to suppress this error message in my WebBrowser control?

Comment: What is the error message? If it is actually a Silverlight error being reported via JavaScript then it can be disabled in the Silverlight.js, but you should not need to suppress JavaScript errors. Is it just because you have IE script debugging on?

Answer (score 1):

You can try my solution [using a script](http://css.dzone.com/news/disable-javascript-error-wpf) or this one [Based on reflection to set the silent property of web browser control](http://www.brentlamborn.com/post/WPF-Web-Browser-ScriptErrorsSupressed.aspx)